# Weird navigation issue - only one item not working

Tags: html, css

Hi – I’m experiencing a navigation issue on my website ([link here](http://goo.gl/9Xt2b)). If you click on the menu items, they all work EXCEPT the button “Press” (which is related to div #medias). For some reason when clicking this button the page scrolls directly to the page/div “contact”, and not the div #medias. I don’t understand the issue because my menu item links point to the right DIVs and the CSS looks OK too. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: It's working fine on Firefox 14.0.1.

Comment: Thanks - are you sure? Can you see the page where you can download pdf articles? On my side it doesn't work on both safari and firefox...

Comment: No, it is not working fine in FireFox 14.0.1.  It scrolls to the wrong DIV as mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Is it me or #medias doesn't have its `height` set in CSS?

Comment: Height is set #medias {
 height: 1300px; Issue must be somewhere else...

Comment: Line 293 in style.css has an ambiguous character that causes an error. That might be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing an ambiguous character in line 293 in your `style.css` file, the #media `div` is operational correctly.

Comment: Good catch, there was indeed an empty space after the bracket! Thanks a lot. What tool did you use to notice that? Thanks

Comment: @Greg By inspecting the #medias `div`, and by looking at Firefox's style list, it appeared to me that the `height` property wasn't being applied. I took a look at the file and noticed that character was causing an error in the error-console.